# How to convert MySQL DateTime to PHP Y-m-d?

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I need to convert mysql datetime to php `Y-m-d`. Essentially I just need to drop the hh:mm:ss from the datetime. How can I do this?

Furthermore, once I have the PHP dates in the format `Y-m-d` how can I do a comparison of two dates to tell which is higher? For example if I have 12-31-13 and 1-1-14 can I just do if (12-31-13 < 1-1-14)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$formattedDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($mysqlDate));

  if (strtotime($somedate) >strtotime($someotherdate)){
 // do stuff here
 }
```

strtotime standardizes most dates and times into the number of seconds since jan1 1970.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to convert mysql datetime to php Y-m-d. Essentially I just need to drop the hh:mm:ss from the datetime. How can I do this?

Use MySQL's [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function

> Furthermore, once I have the PHP dates in the format Y-m-d how can I do a comparison of two dates to tell which is higher? For example if I have 12-31-13 and 1-1-14 can I just do if (12-31-13 < 1-1-14)?

You can compare [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) objects. (Notice the formats of the dates)

```
$date1 = new DateTime('13-12-31');
$date2 = new DateTime('14-01-01');
if ($date1  < $date2)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: No. `date()` expects a timestamp as the second parameter and the order of the date parts are incorrect.

Comment: So this: $timestartDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($timestart)); Can I then pass $timestartDate into new DateTime like $date = new DateTime($timestartDate); ?

Comment: I am not sure your original date formats (mm-dd-yy) will work with strtotime but it might. Give it a try and see. You can also use `$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-y','12-31-13')` which is probably better.

Comment: what's the benefit of using this more complex method vs. strtotime?

Comment: DateTime is more flexible and powerful. And more readable, too.

Answer (score 1):

for comparing date use [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime), and [date](http://php.net/date) u can find plenty of examples.

```
$orig = "2000-01-01";
$new = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($orig));
```

after thad you can compare dates like `$orig > $new`